# Write a Hive table with structure into a TSV file

Tags: csv, hive, hiveql

In Hive, how do you use INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY to write a tab separated file with columns that are structures of the schema: array<struct<....>>

This is what I tried so far, but didn't work:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY /some/tmp/location
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ","
SELECT t1.stringCol, t1.structCol, t1.floatCol
FROM table_with_struct as t1;
```

What do I mean by didn't work?

- The file stored does not have a tab separation between the columns.

I have looked for other solutions, but none have worked.

Comment: then what are the fields separated by?

Comment: Interestingly, both float columns and items inside the structure get separated by a "\N".
I should clarify that I am also writing into a hdfs folder, but that hasn't been a problem when just writing csv files.